# z-index doesn't do what it supposed to?

Tags: css, z-index

It would be great if somebody could put light on how to solve this issue.
I have been working on this for a while now, trying various things. It started a simple z-index  experiment, but for some reason, no mater what I try the divs wont overlap.
It is a pretty simple structure just now, with basically a "wrapper" and two relative positioned divs inside with different z-index-es. What do I miss here? Please help!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/perren/qeuve0bd/7/)

HTML:

```
<section id="wrapper">
  <section id="content">
    &nbsp;
    abcdefg
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
  </section>
  <section id="border">
    abcd
  </section>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
html{width:100%; height:100%}
    body{
        margin:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:#bababa;
        }
    #wrapper{
        width:80%;
        margin:0px auto;
        background:yellow;
        border:2px solid green;
        }
   #border{
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        background:blue;
        z-index: 1;
        }
    #content{
        position:relative;
        width:80%;
        margin:0px auto;
        background:red;
        z-index: 2;
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand what DIV you want to be above the other?

Comment: What's the expected outcome?

Comment: I think OP wants the content to overlap the border, except the blocks are relatively positioned so no overlapping

Comment: Seems to be everything works perfect according to your code what is the expected result.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Sorry guys, I added the code in the meantime. What I need is the blue div below the red one. At the moment the blue starts where the red ends. Both should be within the yellow one.

Comment: @Paulie_D none here is clear what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @robperren The "Blue" one is inside the "Yellow" one, you just cant see the "Yellow" because you have set the div to be '100% width' set it to be 80% like the "Red" one and you will see the "Yellow". Also add margin: 0 auto; to the "Blue"

Comment: Simply the #border which is blue with z-index:1 should be below #content with z-index:2. Both have position declared, but I am not sure what I am missing still.

Comment: And check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qeuve0bd/9/) the red  already goes top of the your blue border

Comment: What I would like to see is the red, overlaps the blue one. Both starts at the top of the page. The yellow is just a placeholder. I tried them without the yellow but without any joy. So the yellow is not a problem, just the blue and red.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I wondered how to force the blue start at the top and underneath the red.

Comment: I have updated the link. Took out the yellow as it is confusing and not really part of the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/perren/qeuve0bd/11/

Comment: You want this I guess? http://jsfiddle.net/qeuve0bd/12/

Comment: Thanks Samih. This is exactly what I need, but with both divs relatively positioned. I am not sure if it is possible at all, but everything would have to be relative.

Comment: Well the obvious question to me is: If you want the red section to appear inside the blue one, why don't you put the red one inside the blue one?

Comment: No, I will have a wrapper for both. The blue one will always fill the size of the wrapper and the red will hold the content. When the content grows and red expands it will push the height of the wrapper down and the blue will scale with it. I appreciate it might sounds a bit complicated...

Comment: No actually it sounds quite simple to me. Is this right? http://jsfiddle.net/qeuve0bd/13/

Comment: Removed some of the unneccessary stuff and added the yellow back in. Is this still on the right track? http://jsfiddle.net/qeuve0bd/13/

Comment: I have to go now but here is one more, showing that the blue content is behind the red.http://jsfiddle.net/qeuve0bd/14/

Comment: Hey Samih. You had a great solution. I thought about combining  relative and absolute content, but without your <span>-tweak it wouldn't work. Thanks a lot for your help. I implemented into the real experiment and with a little jquery help it does what it supposed to do. This is the link to the interim version with the background images: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5791486/sppg/web/index3.html
It looks a mess at the moment but I can now take it to the next step. Thanks again!!!!!!